# Matrix-valued differential equation $A'(t)=A(t)B(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

> How to solve matrix-valued differential equations of type $$A'(t)=A(t)B(t) \tag 1$$

All the given functions are square matrices of dimension $3$ and only $A(t)$ is invertible (not $B(t)$ or $A'(t)$). $A(t)$ is a rotation matrix. We know $A(0)$.  $A(t)$ is unknown. $B(t)$ is available in explicit form.

NB :: Please provide any suggestions or useful links about solutions

Comment: What does the prime denote, what do you wish to find and have you had any succes yourself in working towards a solution?

Comment: What is $R(0)$?

Comment: What is the explicit for of $B(t)$?

Comment: It is a linear interpolation between two constant vectors of dimension$3 \times 1$. Let $K_0,K_1$ are constants.. Then $B(t)=[(1-t)K_0+ tK_1)]_{\times}$..  $[\hspace{.2cm} ]_{\times}$ is skew symmetric matrix with diagonals zero and is non invertible. $[\hspace{.2cm} ]_{\times}$ is defined as follows if $P= \left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \\ z \end{array}\right)$ then    $[P ]_{\times}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
   0 & -z  & y  \\
   z  & 0 & -x  \\
  -y  & x  & 0 \\
   \end{array} \right)$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $B(t)$ is, say, continuous, we can define a matrix $C(t)$ by
$$
C(t):=\int_0^t B(s) \, ds.
$$
If $C(t)B(t)=B(t)C(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$, then we can put the differential equation in the equivalent form (this is basically just the technique of multiplying by an integrating factor)
$$
\frac{d}{dt} A(t)e^{-C(t)}=0,
$$
which has the solution $A(t)=A(0)e^{C(t)}$.

Following the suggestion of jnez71, the non-commutative case also has a satisfying solution. Suppose for simplicity that $B:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is continuous. Denote by $\mathcal X$ the Banach space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with norm $\lVert f \rVert = \sup_{0\leqslant t \leqslant 1} \lVert f(t) \rVert_{\text{op}}$. Let $B(\mathcal X)$ denote the Banach algebra of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal X$. We will look for a solution $A\in \mathcal{X}$.

Define $T_B\in B(\mathcal X)$ by
$$
(T_B f)(t) := \int_0^t f(x) B(x) \, dx.
$$
Then the equation $A'(t)=A(t)B(t)$ with initial condition $A(0)=1$ may equivalently be written as
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
A = 1 + T_B A.
\end{equation}
Note that, for $m\geqslant 2$,
$$
(T_B^{m+1} f)(t) = \int ^t _0 \int ^{x_{m+1}}_0 \cdots \int ^{x_2}_0 f(x_{1}) B(x_{1})B(x_2)\cdots B(x_{m+1})  \, dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{m+1}.
$$
We therefore find
$$
\tag{2}
\lVert T_B^{m+1}\rVert \leqslant \frac{\lVert B \rVert ^{m+1}}{(m+1)!} \overset{m\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow} 0.
$$
Thus, the Neumann series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty T_B^j = (1-T_B)^{-1}$ is well defined.

Uniqueness of A: By repeated application of formula (1), we find $A = \sum_{j=0}^m T_B^j 1 + T_B^{m+1} A$. According to relation (2), we therefore have $A = \sum_{j=0}^\infty T_B^j 1$.

Existence: It is straightforward to verify that $A := (1-T_B)^{-1} 1$ satisfies formula (1).

Final comments: We have thus found the formula
\begin{align*}
A(t) &= 1 + \int_{0}^t B(x_1) \, dx_1 + \int ^t _0 \int ^{x_2}_0 B(x_{1}) B(x_{2})  \, dx_1 dx_{2}\\
& \qquad + \sum_{j=3}^\infty \int ^t _0 \int^{x_j}_0 \cdots \int ^{x_2}_0 B(x_{1})B(x_2) \cdots B(x_{j})  \, dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{j}.
\end{align*}
Except for the ordering of the matrices, this is the [Peano-Baker series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano-Baker_series). In the publication linked to by jnez71, 'Product Integration, Its History and Applications' by Slavík, this formula appears as a formula for the right product integral. If $A$ is unitary and we make the replacement $B \rightarrow -i\tilde B$, the formula is known to practitioners of quantum mechanics as the [Dyson series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series).

*Slavík, Antonín*, [**Product integration, its history and applications**](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~prusv/ncmm/notes/download/product_integration.pdf), Dějiny Matematiky / History of Mathematics 29; Jindřich Nečas Center for Mathematical Modeling Lecture Notes 1. Prague: Matfyzpress (ISBN 80-7378-006-2). 147 p. (2007). [ZBL1216.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1216.28001).

Comment: But commutative is an issue..It is not guaranteed always

Comment: @Rejo_Slash:  I'll say "Amen!" to that!

Comment: @Rejo_Slash You're right, this answer assumed commutivity; not very satisfying. For the general case, look [here](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~prusv/ncmm/notes/download/product_integration.pdf)